# Different issues with the Workbook_Open event

Tags: excel, vba, events

After some research on the internet and on Stackoverflow, I'm stuck on some elements about the functionning of the event : Workbook_Open (which will surely seems simple to you).
I wrote the following code :

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

' Désactivation des évènements
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Put the back color of a button to red
' line 1
 CB1.BackColor = &HC0&

' Modify the RowHeight of a line
' line 2
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Search").Rows("12:12").RowHeight = 800

' Réactive l'évènement
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Precisions:
CB1 is the name of a button implanted on an excel sheet called "Search"

I have two different problems :

Problem n°1 :
Excel doesn't seem to recongnize the CB1 variable outside of a code written on the "Search" sheet. I don't understand why. Is the variable CB1 not supposed to be available for all the code of the Workbook ?

Problem n°2
I simply do not see why Line 2 doesn't work.
Even when I write it in another procedure that I call afterwards.

Anyone can give me a suggestions ?
Best regards and thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

' Désactivation des évènements
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Put the back color of a button to red
' line 1
'sheet specification a requirement
 Sheets("Search").CB1.BackColor = &HC0&

' Modify the RowHeight of a line
' line 2
' maximum row height is 409
Sheets("Search").Rows(12).RowHeight = 409

' Réactive l'évènement
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Please see the following link for maximum row height in Excel: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  
For me "Worksheets" and "Sheets" were interchangeable in a VBA code.
And I did not know there were limitations on cell size.